# React Data Grid shows bad

Tags: reactjs, grid, react-data-grid

I have a problem with ReactDataGrid component. I have already installed react-data-grid. The code is the same as in the reac grid's web:

```
const columns = [
  { key: 'id', name: 'ID' },
  { key: 'title', name: 'Title' },
  { key: 'count', name: 'Count' }];

const rows = [{ id: 0, title: 'row1', count: 20 }, { id: 1, title: 'row1', count: 40 }, { id: 2, title: 'row1', count: 60 }];


class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ReactDataGrid
        columns={columns}
        rowGetter={i => rows[i]}
        rowsCount={3}
        minHeight={150} />
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

and i get:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbmMy.png)

Thank you!

Comment: Seems like css issue

Comment: Your code is same as docs and It doesn’t need to import style manually, so you can check that css loads in network tab of browser or you can re-install package.

Answer (score 4):

Import the CSS like so :

```
import 'react-data-grid/dist/react-data-grid.css';
```

It should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import React from "react";
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
    import ReactDataGrid from "react-data-grid";

    const columns = [
      { key: "id", name: "ID", editable: true },
      { key: "title", name: "Title", editable: true },
      { key: "count", name: "Count", editable: true }
    ];

    const rows = [
      { id: 0, title: "row1", count: 20 },
      { id: 1, title: "row1", count: 40 },
      { id: 2, title: "row1", count: 60 }
    ];

    class App extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <ReactDataGrid
            columns={columns}
            rowGetter={i => rows[i]}
            rowsCount={3}
            minHeight={150}
            enableCellSelect={true}
          />
        );
      }
    }

    const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/rdg-cell-editing-h8bnr

the answer is in the above code this above code is working

Comment: it seems that the problem is my project. I run the same code in codesandbox and it works fine, but in my project it does not :(

Comment: try to make use the inspect element and find where is the problem

Comment: or try to debug the thing using divide and conquer strategy

Comment: hello! i downgrade the react-data-grid version and now it works fine! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to downgrade. The issue is that the css is not being imported.
If you can import css from node-modules, it'll work.
Workaround for me was I took the whole css and we are now self-maintaining the css, making changes when needed.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't load the css either, I got around this by including

```
import ReactDataGrid from 'react-data-grid/dist/react-data-grid.min.js';
```

instead of

```
import ReactDataGrid from 'react-data-grid';
```